# Docker on AWS JVM CPU limit

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-fargate

I launch our spring boot application in docker container on AWS Fargate service, so once the CPU consumption is reached more then 100% the container is stopped Docker OOM-killer with error

> Reason: OutOfMemoryError: Container killed due to memory usage

On metrics we can see that CPU becomes more then 100%. It seems after some time of profiling we found CPU consuming code, but my question is, how CPU can be grater than 100%?

Is it some way to say JVM use only 100%?

I remember we had similar issue with memory consumption. I read a lot of articles about cgroups, and the solution was found to specify

> -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap

So when you launch docker with option -m=512 heap size will be 1/4 of mac size. The heap size can also be tuned with option

> -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2

which will allocate 1/2 of docker memory for heap.
Should I use something similar for CPU?
I read article https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-se-support-for-docker-cpu-and-memory-limits, but it tells that

> As of Java SE 8u131, and in JDK 9, the JVM is Docker-aware with
>   respect to Docker CPU limits transparently. That means if
>   -XX:ParalllelGCThreads, or -XX:CICompilerCount are not specified as command line options, the JVM will apply the Docker CPU limit as the
>   number of CPUs the JVM sees on the system. The JVM will then adjust
>   the number of GC threads and JIT compiler threads just like it would
>   as if it were running on a bare metal system with number of CPUs set
>   as the Docker CPU limit.

Docker command is used to start

```
docker run -d .... -e JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XshowSettings:vm' -m=512 -c=256 ...
```

Java version is used

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-1~deb9u1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Some additional info on app during start up

```
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 123.75M
    Ergonomics Machine Class: client
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

ParallelGCThreads                         = 0   
CICompilerCount                          := 2
CICompilerCountPerCPU                     = true
```

Answer (score 2):

I found answer to my question.
The behaviour to identify number of processors to use was fixed in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146115

> Number of CPUs
>
> ---
>
> Use a combination of number_of_cpus() and cpu_sets() in order to determine how many processors are available to
>   the process and adjust the JVMs os::active_processor_count
>   appropriately. The number_of_cpus() will be calculated based on the
>   cpu_quota() and cpu_period() using this formula: number_of_cpus() =
>   cpu_quota() / cpu_period(). If cpu_shares has been setup for the
>   container, the number_of_cpus() will be calculated based on
>   cpu_shares()/1024. 1024 is the default and standard unit for
>   calculating relative cpu usage in cloud based container management
>   software.
>
> Also add a new VM flag (-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=xx) that allows the
>   number of CPUs to be overridden. This flag will be honored even if
>   UseContainerSupport is not enabled.

So on AWS you generally setup *cpu_shares* on task definition level.
Before jvm fix it was calculated incorrectly.

On java8 version < 191: cpu_shares()/1024 = 256/1024 = was identified as 2

After migration on java8 version > 191: cpu_shares()/1024 = 256/1024 = was identified as 1

The code to test

```
val version = System.getProperty("java.version")
val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
val processors = runtime.availableProcessors()
logger.info("========================== JVM Info ==========================")
logger.info("Java version is: {}", version)
logger.info("Available processors: {}", processors)
```

The sample output

```
"Java version is: 1.8.0_212"
"Available processors: 1"
```

I hope it will help someone, as I can't find the answer anywhere (spring-issues-tracker, AWS support, etc.)